# Chrome is rendering partial pixels when background-clip property is set to content-box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a website that uses foundation grid so some widths are percentage based and the content is also getting centered to the screen width which means some things aren't perfectly alinged to the pixel grid. This was never an issue until now. I would say about a month ago I noticed in Chrome ONLY I would see very thin lines (less than one pixel) wide where two percentage based containers are connected.
See here: [image]

**Update:**

It was pointed out to me in the comments that this is caused by the background-clip property set to content-box on the columns. See this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/odpv8jgx/

You can see the blue background between the two containers.
I still stand by that fact that this wasnt an issue few weeks ago, so something must have changed in Chrome. So is this a bug? I've reported it to on chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=957946

```css
.row{
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.left{
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
  background-color: orange;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.right{
  flex-basis: 66.66666%;
  background-color: green;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.left,
.right{
  background-clip: content-box;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    b
  </div>
</div>
```

**Original details**

Now in the CSS there is 0 padding, margin and border on the columns. And if I check the same page in IE, Edge, Firefox and Opera this gap never appears there. So it really seems to me like chrome started treating this in a different way to the other browsers. I also noticed that if I start manually resizing the Chromes browser width the gap will completely diasappear for some resultions which seems to me like when the browser manages to perfectly align both the containers on the pixel grid the gap doesnt get created. I've even had this happen on the vertical axis see here

[image]

Again even though the is no css margin/padding/border there is a tiny gap on some resoltuions between the containers and since their parent container has a blue background the background shows inbetween. This also occurs only in Chrome.

Is there any way to avoid this? Or is this just some bad code they released and it will get removed in future versions?

Here is a link to the page that gets has the gap on the horizontal axis
https://www.idc.com/getdoc.jsp?containerId=lcEUR145039919

Comment: Sub-pixel rendering is a known issue in Chrome. Usually a small 1px negative margin fixes it. Or a `transform3D(0,0,0)`

Comment: It's because of this CSS: `.column:not(.row) { background-clip: content-box; }` remove it, or override it with `background-clip: border-box;`

Comment: @elveti well I can't remove it because thats how our layout works. It so that we dont have to wrap everything in extra divs when we use background color... Thank you for finding the root issue. So it means it not only the not perfectly aligned grid but its that in combination with the background clip. I will try to create a simple fiddle that isolates this.

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane https://jsfiddle.net/2jeamy0o/2/ here it's showcased. It's a combination of `background-clip`, widths in % and a parent width that is not divisible, so the children have widths with decimal values. You could trick it with `box-shadow` but yeah, not the most elegant solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bug reported has been aaccepted by Chrome devs. It's already assigned to someone for fixing.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=957946